# I can't create functions on SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, ora-06550

I'm trying to create very basic *function* to learn.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AddNumbers (
    num1 NUMBER,
    num2 NUMBER
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
    result NUMBER;
BEGIN
    result := num1 + num2;
    RETURN result;
END;
```

But this function wasn't compiling properly. Here is the error:

> ```
> Error starting at line : 7 in command -
> BEGIN
>     result := num1 + num2;
>     RETURN result;
> END;
> Error report -
> ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
> PLS-00201: identifier 'RESULT' must be declared
> ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored
> ORA-06550: line 3, column 5:
> PLS-00372: In a procedure, RETURN statement cannot contain an expression
> ORA-06550: line 3, column 5:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored
> 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
> *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
> *Action:
> ```

When I try to create a function, I always encounter this `ORA-06550` error.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with code you posted, but I presume that you don't use SQL Developer properly. That error looks as if you *selected* executable part of function and ... well, *executed* it:

[image]

Don't select anything; just press CTRL + ENTER to create function (or 2nd button in toolbar, named "Execute script"; or press F5). Once you create it, **then** use it, e.g.

```
select addnumbers(1, 2) From dual;
```

Additional note: PL/SQL code should be terminated with a slash character. If you don't do that and try to run that SELECT (without *selecting* it), you'll get another error ("PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" ").

---

Demo:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addnumbers (
  2      num1 NUMBER,
  3      num2 NUMBER
  4  ) RETURN NUMBER IS
  5      result NUMBER;
  6  BEGIN
  7      result := num1 + num2;
  8      RETURN result;
  9  END;
 10  /

Function created.

SQL> SELECT addnumbers(1, 2) FROM dual;

ADDNUMBERS(1,2)
---------------
              3

SQL>
```

SQL Developer screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I did what you said. I didn't get the plsql compilation error while creating function. But function is still created with red cross. The function "addnumbers" has been created without a begin and end block.

Comment: create or replace FUNCTION AddNumbers (
    num1 NUMBER,
    num2 NUMBER
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
    result_number NUMBER                                                               
 And when I'm executing the select command ORA-06575: Package or function ADDNUMBERS is in an invalid state
06575. 00000 -  "Package or function %s is in an invalid state"
*Cause:    A SQL statement references a PL/SQL function that is in an
           invalid state. Oracle attempted to compile the function, but
           detected errors.
*Action:   Check the SQL statement and the PL/SQL function

Comment: When I use SQL Plus to create functions, it works, but when I try to run the script using SQL Developer's run script button, F5, or Ctrl+Enter, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: I posted another screenshot which shows SQL Developer session; as I said, *everything* works OK.